# Java Criteria builder for Null value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have using java criteria builder, this is my code

```
     RepositoryFactory.emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("onezero");
            String Symbol = "EURUSD";
            TradingHistory tradingHistorys = RepositoryFactory.getTradingHistoryRepo().findPriceEmpty(Symbol);
            String symbols = tradingHistorys.getSymbol();
            Date created = tradingHistorys.getCreated_at();

public TradingHistory findPriceEmpty( final String Symbol) throws SQLException{
          WhereClause<TradingHistory> conditions = new WhereClause<TradingHistory>() {

            public void defineWhere(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, CriteriaQuery<TradingHistory> criteriaQuery,
                    Root<TradingHistory> root) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                criteriaQuery.select(root).where((criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("Symbol"), Symbol)
                        ,(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("Price"), null)))));
            }
        };
        return singleResult(conditions,null,0,1,0);

    }
```

when i use is null()

```
    public TradingHistory findPriceEmpty( final String Symbol) throws SQLException{
              WhereClause<TradingHistory> conditions = new WhereClause<TradingHistory>() {

                public void defineWhere(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, CriteriaQuery<TradingHistory> criteriaQuery,
                        Root<TradingHistory> root) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    criteriaQuery.select(root).where((criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("Symbol"), Symbol)
                            ,(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("Price").isNull(), root)))));
                }
            };
            return singleResult(conditions,null,0,1,0);

        }
```

i got error like

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: is near line 1, column 157 [select generatedAlias0 from com.dxtr.hibernate.model.TradingHistory as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.Symbol=:param0 ) and ( generatedAlias0.Price is null=generatedAlias0 )]
```

my question how to search when price = null ? because when i use that code i got error Java null pointer exception. so there is problem for us...

please help me for fix it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you would use [isNull()](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/comparison) as in the following sample:

```
public TradingHistory findPriceEmpty( final String Symbol) throws SQLException{
          WhereClause<TradingHistory> conditions = new WhereClause<TradingHistory>() {

            public void defineWhere(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, CriteriaQuery<TradingHistory> criteriaQuery,
                    Root<TradingHistory> root) {                criteriaQuery.select(root).where((criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("Symbol"), Symbol),(criteriaBuilder.isNull(root.get("Price")))));
            }
        };
        return singleResult(conditions,null,0,1,0);
```

Hope that helps. If you run into further problems, do leave a comment.